# LISTAGG function in SQLPLUS on ORACLE 11g error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I currently have these tables, my main aim is to automatically populate the event_item_exhibited column, by concatenating category and item_number from TABLE "ITEMS" . 
I attempted using the LISTAGG function after much research, but I am getting ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

```
CREATE TABLE ITEMOWNERS (itemOwner_number INT NOT NULL CHECK(itemOwner_number >= 1000 AND itemOwner_number <= 2999), 
          itemOwner_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,                         
          itemOwner_address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          first_contact TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,                                                         
          PRIMARY KEY (itemOwner_number));



CREATE TABLE ITEMS (lent_by_itemOwner_number INT NOT NULL,
                    category CHAR (3) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT chk_category_input CHECK (category IN ('LDN','STH', 'MNC','SCT')),    
                    item_number NCHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                    item_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,               
                    item_value NUMBER NOT NULL ,    
                    item_description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,            
                    FOREIGN KEY (lent_by_itemOwner_number) REFERENCES ITEMOWNERS(itemOwner_number)); 

CREATE TABLE EVENTS (event_number INT NOT NULL CHECK(event_number >= 3000 AND event_number <= 3999),
                 event_item_exhibited VARCHAR(6) ,                                      
                 title  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,                            
                 event_description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,                  
                 PRIMARY KEY (event_number));
```

**The function I created is the following;**

```
SELECT event_number,
   LISTAGG(category, '/',item_number,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category AND item_number) AS event_item_exhibited  
FROM (
   SELECT UNIQUE
          event_number,
     FROM EVENTS
   )
 GROUP BY event_number;
```

I have attached a example of my aim for the output.
http://oi44.tinypic.com/2ur2dn4.jpg

**Here is what I have done after your recommendation;**

```
CREATE TABLE ITEMOWNERS (itemOwner_number INT NOT NULL CHECK(itemOwner_number >= 1000 AND itemOwner_number <= 2999), 
          itemOwner_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,                         
          itemOwner_address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          first_contact TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,                                                         
          PRIMARY KEY (itemOwner_number));



CREATE TABLE ITEMS (lent_by_itemOwner_number INT NOT NULL,
                    category CHAR (3) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT chk_category_input CHECK (category IN ('LDN','STH', 'MNC','SCT')),    
                    item_number NCHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                    item_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,               
                    item_value NUMBER NOT NULL ,    
                    item_description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,            
                    FOREIGN KEY (lent_by_itemOwner_number) REFERENCES ITEMOWNERS(itemOwner_number)); 

CREATE TABLE EVENTS (event_number INT NOT NULL CHECK(event_number >= 3000 AND event_number <= 3999),
                 event_item_exhibited VARCHAR(7) ,                                      
                 title  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,                            
                 event_description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,                  
                 PRIMARY KEY (event_number));


INSERT INTO ITEMOWNERS VALUES ('1001','Edward','London',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO ITEMOWNERS VALUES ('1002','Michael','Nottingham',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);



INSERT into ITEMS VALUES ('1001','LDN','121','Penmate','500','Unique pen');
INSERT into ITEMS VALUES ('1002','MNC','131','Trampoline','1500','Professional equipment');


INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('3001','LDN/121','PEN SHOW', 'Exclusive show of unique pens');
INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES ('3002','MNC/131','Jump Club', 'Enjoy a session of tampolining');
```

Final required output is this.
http://oi39.tinypic.com/35a80on.jpg

```
ITEMOWNER_NUMBER  ITEMOWNER_NAME     ITEMOWNER_ADDRESS  FIRST_CONTACT                                            
        1001      Edward             London             27-NOV-13 15.14.43.899677                                                                          
        1002      Michael            Nottingham         27-NOV-13 15.14.43.930465                                                                           



LENT_BY_ITEMOWNER_NUMBER CATEGORY ITEM_NUMBER ITEM_NAME  ITEM_VALUE ITEM_DESCRIPTION

 1001                     LDN     121         Penmate    500        Unique pen
 1002                     MNC     131         Trampoline 1500       Professional equipment



   EVENT_NUMBER EVENT_ITEM  TITLE      EVENT_DESCRIPTION                                                                                               

           3001 LDN/121     PEN SHOW   Exclusive show of unique pens                                                                                           
           3002 MNC/131     Jump Club  Enjoy a session of tampolining
```

Now my whole entire question is based solely on how can I have the database populate EVENT_ITEM by it's self by merging CATEGORY & ITEM_NUMBER from TABLE ITEMS into the coloumn EVENT_ITEM as shown above.

Comment: Followup to my original comment - I just had a chance to circle back on this, and see you've got much bigger issues here than some simple syntax errors.  I think your first step in the right direction is expressing your problem statement a lot more clearly by (1) writing create table scripts that actually work (in Oracle, not SQL Server), (2) writing insert statements that load meaningful data, and then (3) presenting a desired result set that matches your data, with a clear explanation of how you arrived at that desired result.

Comment: I have updated it, there is no issue at all of manually entering it, however I wanted to see how I can make it an automated process.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear - I meant, in addition to giving INSERTS to load a meaningful sample of data, show us the expected results that you want to see for that data (along with a clear explanation of how those results should be obtained).  That will ensure responders have a crystal clear idea of what you're trying to automated...

Comment: I think I have added everything to show where I am stuck on.

Comment: Essentially just merging CATEGORY with ITEM_NUMBER into EVENTS table.

Answer (score 1):

```
LISTAGG(category, '/',item_number,',') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category AND item_number) AS event_item_exhibited
```

Couple syntax errors there, should be

```
LISTAGG(category || '/' || item_number,',') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category , item_number) AS event_item_exhibited
```

Comment: Thanks, seemed to help get past the current error, however I have come across another issue now. "ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "ITEM_NUMBER": invalid identifier"  is this because it's within another table? Surely category should have given the same error then